# Do I need to remove test device when publishing on Admob Android?

Tags: android, admob

Which one I need to remove when publishing ?

```
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
```

Comment: Why would you need a test device for publishing?

Comment: @ShadabK: i want to understand the way this method processes with test device when publishing

Comment: @Brascelok https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads here says you should remove those

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to remove them.

It will just mean that when the app is run on that device you will continue to get test ads on that device.

Comment: Does it mean that my app will display real ads on others device?  Does this code .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) make others device like EMULATOR when publishing ?